# How to get the RequestURL (General Header) in Google Chrome using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url

The general headers in google chrome includes the requestURL string on every http request(eg: Request URL:chrome-extension://bdfnieppndfdhcgbmhfdlgdjegclkomk/static/js/region.js)
I would like to extract this but the only method I am aware of is window.location.href which does not include the extension.

Comment: Are you making a chrome extension and want to access the urls in that context or is it more generic in the sense that you want to access the request url using javascript?

Comment: I am making an extension and want to identify the request url that will tell me when the request is made by an extension.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use the [chrome.tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) and use the `getCurrent` method.

You would just want to do something like:

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab){
    console.log(tab.url);
});
```

Add the following permission to your *manifest.json* file:

```
 {
    "name": "My extension",
    ...
    "permissions": [
      "tabs"
    ],
    ...
  }
```

Hope it gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: I have tried this but it gets me the URL of the website being loaded. I want to identify which requests were generated by an extension. Which is why I am looking for the RequestURL in the general headers(in the network tab of inspect element). Or do you have any other method to identify which requests are generated by an extension

Comment: I see. You might want to look at the [webRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-HttpHeaders) then.  The docs say `The webRequest API only exposes requests that the extension has permission to see, given its host permissions. Moreover, only the following schemes are accessible: http://, https://, ftp://, file://, or chrome-extension://.`